# How can I add a group to an admin role in my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

It used to be possible to add a group of users to roles (Administrators/Developers/Testers) - we have some apps with this still set up.  See this [obselete Facebook blog post from 2011 detailing this functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/531/).

However, the add group functionality seems to have been removed - add there's no add group option any more, just "Type in a name or ID of the user you want to add".

Am I right in thinking it's now impossible to make add a group to a role of a Facebook app?

Comment: Does anyone know anything about this? Managing 10+ user's roles in 10+ apps is real PITA.